# Como exibir e fazer a contagem dos dias de uma semana entre duas datas usando javascript e php

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo a tabela geral tb_turg que guarda os registros assim:

```
idmodg: 13 (codigo do módulo)
codturg: 101 (código da turma)
iniclasg: 2020-01-13 (data de inicio)
terclasg: 2020-02-21 (data de termino)
weekg: 1,3,5 (dias da semana que tem curso, neste caso: segunda, quarta e sexta)
```

Cada aluno possui uma tabela. O aluno id 1 possui a tabela tb_z1 e guarda os registros assim:

```
idcur   | codtur    | diafrq
13  | 101       | 2020-01-13
13  | 101       | 2020-01-17
13  | 101       | 2020-01-20
13  | 101       | 2020-01-22
13  | 101       | 2020-01-29
13  | 101       | 2020-01-31
13  | 101       | 2020-02-03
13  | 101       | 2020-02-05
13  | 101       | 2020-02-07
etc...
```

Como calcular:
Quantos dias e quais os dias da tabela tb_turg da data de inicio (iniclasg) até a data de término (terclasg), mas somente nos dias especificados na semana (weekg), que seriam

```
2020-01-13, 2020-01-15, 2020-01-17, 
2020-01-20, 2020-01-22, 2020-01-24, 
2020-01-27, 2020-01-29, 2020-01-31,
2020-02-03, 2020-02-05, 2020-02-07, 
2020-02-10, 2020-02-12, 2020-02-14,
2020-02-17, 2020-02-19, 2020-02-21,
```

18 DIAS

Quantos dias de frequência teve o aluno id 1
09 DIAS (por exemplo)

Obtido os dados, deve-se verificar:
Quantos dias de FALTA obteve o aluno id 1?

Preciso gerar um relatório passando o código do módulo (13) e o código da turma (101) via GET. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado

SAÍDA:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
MINHAS TENTATIVAS:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');


$arrphp = $_GET['arrphp'];
$idmods = $_GET['idmods'];
$mod = $_GET['idmods'];     //----- Para escrever no SELECT do SQL
$codtur = $_GET['codtur'];
$tur = $_GET['turma'];
$prof = $_GET['prof'];

//if ($idmods) { include "../../sys/sqlmod.php"; }
//if ($mbkgmod == "#FFFFFF") { $borda = "border: 1px solid #ccc"; } else { $borda = ""; }

if ($tur == "A") { $nturma = "Turma 1"; $vog = "a"; } if ($tur == "B") { $nturma = "Turma 2"; $vog = "b"; }
if ($tur == "C") { $nturma = "Turma 3"; $vog = "c"; } if ($tur == "D") { $nturma = "Turma 4"; $vog = "d"; }


    $sqlturg = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT codturg,profg,iniclasg,terclasg,weekg,classg FROM tb_turg WHERE codturg = '$codtur'");
    $rowtg = $sqlturg->fetch_assoc();
    $profg = $rowtg["profg"];
    $iniclasg = $rowtg["iniclasg"];
    $terclasg = $rowtg["terclasg"];
    $weekg = $rowtg["weekg"];
    $classg = $rowtg["classg"];

    if ($iniclasg) { $nwiniclasg = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($iniclasg)); } else { $nwiniclasg = ""; }
    if ($terclasg) { $nwterclasg = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($terclasg)); } else { $nwterclasg = "ABERTA"; }
    if ($nwterclasg == "ABERTA") { $calcnwter = date("d/m/Y"); } else { $calcnwter = $nwterclasg; }

    //if ($profg) { $mprofm = $profg; include "../../sys/sqlprof.php"; }

    if ($terclasg == "") { $nwtermino = date('Y-m-d'); }



?>

<?php //echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style>
.tb-freq-def td {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<table class='tb-freq-def' id='table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='width:calc(100% - 25px);border-top:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #000;'>
    <tr>
        <td width='182' colspan='2' align='center'>Alunos</td>
        <td width='599' align='center'>Frequências</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width='182' colspan='2' align='center'><div class='ames'></div></td>

        <td width='599' align='left'>

        </td>


    </tr>



<?php
$sqlatva = "SELECT idalunos FROM tb_x$mod WHERE cdgtur = '$codtur'";        //ORDER BY idalunos ASC limit 1";
$queryma = $conn->query($sqlatva);
while($rowatva = $queryma->fetch_assoc()) {
$idaa = $rowatva["idalunos"];

//echo "<script>$('#$idaa').hide(0);</script>";

}
?>



<?php
$sqlatv = "SELECT idalunos,cdgtur FROM tb_x$mod WHERE cdgtur = '$codtur'";
$querym = $conn->query($sqlatv);
while($rowatv = $querym->fetch_assoc()) {
$ida = $rowatv["idalunos"];
?>


<?php
$sqlclitur = "SELECT idcli,idatv,nomei,generoi,fotocli FROM tb_cli WHERE idcli = '$ida'";
$queryb = $conn->query($sqlclitur);
while($rowctb = $queryb->fetch_assoc()) {
$cidcli = $rowctb["idcli"];
$cidatv = $rowctb["idatv"];
$cnomei = $rowctb["nomei"];
$cgeneroi = $rowctb["generoi"];
$cphoto = $rowctb["fotocli"];

if ( ($cgeneroi == "M") || ($cgeneroi == "") ) { $vgl = "o"; }
if ($cgeneroi == "F") { $vgl = "a"; }

$ursarra = explode(' ', $cnomei);
$nwcnomei = $ursarra[0];        //." ".$ursarra[1];

//----- Foto do Beneficiário
$codUserF = $cidcli;
$upload_dir = "data/photo/clients/";

$user_foto_prefix = "_ben.jpg?".date("YmdHis");
$user_atual_name = $codUserF.$user_foto_prefix;
$user_foto_location = $upload_dir.$user_atual_name;

$_dir = "../photo/clients/";
$_foto_prefix = "_ben.jpg";
$_atual_name = $codUserF.$_foto_prefix;
$_foto_location = $_dir.$_atual_name;

if ($cidatv == "X") {
$inatva = "<div class='emCursorP emRed3' onclick='benExclur(\"$cnomei|$vgl\");' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;-webkit-filter:blur(50px);z-index:1;'></div>";
$inatvf = "<div class='emCursorP' onclick='benExclur(\"$cnomei|$vgl\");' style='position:absolute;width:60px;height:60px;border-radius:100%;z-index:2;'></div>";
$inatvb = "display:none";
$inaticon = "<div class='emRed3 emWhtA emFont11' style='position:absolute;width:20px;height:20px;bottom:0;right:0;border-radius:100%;z-index:1;'><i class='fa fa-trash-alt'></i></div>";
} else {
$inatva = "";
$inatvf = "";
$inatvb = "";
$inaticon = "";
}

?>
    <tr>


<div style='position:relative;*width:100px;*margin-bottom:10px;'>
<!-- ===== INÍCIO FOTO BENEFICIÁRIO ===== -->
<div style='position:relative;width:40px;*border-radius:100%;'>

<?php echo $inaticon; ?>
<?php echo $inatvf; ?>


<?php if (file_exists($_foto_location)) { ?>
<div class='' style='position:relative;*border-radius:100%;'>
<div class='fotoe<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fotof<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fa fotog<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='position:absolute;line-height:1;z-index:2;'></div>
<?php $f_user = "<img class='foto<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='width:40px;*border-radius:100%;border:1px solid #f4f4f4;margin:0 auto;' src='$user_foto_location'>"; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!file_exists($_foto_location) && ($cgeneroi == 'M')) { ?>
<div class='' style='position:relative;*border-radius:100%;'>
<div class='fotoe<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fotof<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fa fotog<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='position:absolute;line-height:1;z-index:2;'></div>
<?php $f_user = "<img class=' foto<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='width:40px;*border-radius:100%;margin:0 auto;' src='data/photo/fotos/_m.png'>"; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!file_exists($_foto_location) && ($cgeneroi == 'F')) { ?>
<div class='' style='position:relative;*border-radius:100%;'>
<div class='fotoe<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fotof<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fa fotog<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='position:absolute;line-height:1;z-index:2;'></div>
<?php $f_user = "<img class=' foto<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='width:40px;*border-radius:100%;margin:0 auto;' src='data/photo/fotos/_f.png'>"; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!file_exists($_foto_location) && ($cgeneroi == '')) { ?>
<div class='' style='position:relative;*border-radius:100%;'>
<div class='fotoe<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fotof<?php echo $cidcli; ?> emMaiusc'></div>
<div class='fa fotog<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='position:absolute;line-height:1;z-index:2;'></div>
<?php $f_user = "<img class=' foto<?php echo $cidcli; ?>' style='width:40px;*border-radius:100%;margin:0 auto;' src='data/photo/fotos/_i.png'>"; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- ===== FINAL FOTO BENEFICIÁRIO ===== -->
</div>
<?php } ?>



        <td width='605' colspan='3'>

<div class='emLineB emTableCell emFont10' style='position:relative;width:71px;height:16px;font-weight:bold;'></div>

<?php
$days = explode(',', $arrphp);
foreach($days as $adddays) {
    $day = $adddays;


    $sqlday = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT diafrq,codtur FROM tb_z$ida WHERE codtur = '$codtur'");
    $rowday = $sqlday->fetch_assoc();
    $diafrq = $rowday["diafrq"];

    if ($diafrq) {
    $arrfrq = explode('-', $diafrq);
    $nwdiafrq = $arrfrq[2];
    } else {
    $nwdiafrq = "";
    }

    if ($nwdiafrq == $day) { $nwcor = "emBlueA"; } else { $nwcor = "emRedA"; }  

if ( ($day) ) { $tbday = "<div class='$nwcor emLineB emTableCell emFont10' style='position:relative;width:18px;min-width:18px;height:16px;font-weight:bold;border-right:1px solid #ccc;'>" . $day . "</div>"; }
    echo $tbday;
}
?>



<?php

$sqlben = "SELECT idnrb,diafrq,diacur,frqcur,codtur FROM tb_z$ida WHERE codtur = '$codtur'";
$queryl = $conn->query($sqlben);


while($rowben = $queryl->fetch_assoc()) { 
$idnrb = $rowben["idnrb"];
$diafrq = $rowben["diafrq"];
$diacur = $rowben["diacur"];
$frqcur = $rowben["frqcur"];

if ($diafrq) {
$arrfrq = explode('-', $diafrq);
$nwdiafrq = $arrfrq[2];
} else {
$nwdiafrq = "";
}

//$freq = [ $f_user ." ". $nwcnomei  =>  [$nwdiafrq], ];



?>




<?php } ?>


</td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo extrair as datas da semana para fazer a contabilidade de quantas frequencias e quantas faltas.

```
DEU CERTO COM A AJUDA DO NOSSO AMIGO FURLAN
```

Eis o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá. 
Não sei se era bem essa a sua dúvida, mas veja se o trecho abaixo lhe ajuda.

> De acordo com https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php, a função `format('w')` é a representação numérica do dia da semana, sendo de 0 (para domingo) até 6 (para sábado).

```
$iniclasg = new DateTime('2020-01-13');
$terclasg = new DateTime('2020-02-21');

$dias_que_tem_aula = array();

while($iniclasg <= $terclasg){

    //Verifica quais dias dentro desse intervalo são segunda, quarta e sexta
    if($iniclasg->format('w') == 1 || $iniclasg->format('w') == 3 || $iniclasg->format('w') == 5){

        //Caso seja 1, 3 ou 5, adiciona a data ao array
        $dias_que_tem_aula[] = $iniclasg->format('Y-m-d');

    }

    //adiciona um dia à data inicial para seguir verificando a partir da próxima data
    $iniclasg = $iniclasg->modify('+1day');
}

//aqui é o resultado da tabela tb_z1, coluna diafrq
$diasfrq = array('2020-01-13', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-20', '2020-01-22', '2020-01-29', '2020-01-31', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-21');

$dias_presentes = count($diasfrq);
$dias_ausentes = (count($dias_que_tem_aula) - $dias_presentes);


echo $dias_presentes;
echo '<br>';
echo $dias_ausentes;
```

> Não me julgue, pois sei que é bem provável que existam maneiras mais performáticas. Contudo, acredito que irá lhe dar uma boa ideia de funcionamento para implementar sua própria solução.

Obs: Todas as datas estão sendo usadas no formado 'Y-m-d'. Portanto, terá que fazer alterações caso esteja utilizando no formado 'd-m-Y'.

Comment: Ô meu amigo, muito obrigado por isso... que Deus te ilumine! Mas o meu problema é colocar isso: if($iniclasg->format('w') == 1 || $iniclasg->format('w') == 3 || $iniclasg->format('w') == 5) de uma forma mais dinâmica... é justamente aqui que eu estou com problema. Exemplo: o Curso A, pode ter os dias 1,3,5 ou 2,4 etc... A coluna weekg guarda os dias da semana justamente assim (numero com vírgula). Como abrir o relatório dinâmico com o mesmo código sendo que: Curso A - Turma 1 - Dias 1,3,5 ou Curso A - Turma 2 - Dias 2,4 ou Curso A - Turma 3 - Dias 1,5. Por favor, me ajude

Comment: Fiz assim e parece estar dando certo: $days = explode(',', $weekg); foreach($days as  $day) { $b = $day; if($novoinic->format('w') == $b) { - O que você acha @Leandro Furlan? Cara quero te dizer que vc salvou "minha vida"... Deus te ilumine!

Comment: Isso mesmo. A função explode irá separar todos os números da string. Vai ficar um foreach dentro de um while e alguns if dentro do foreach, mas acredito que se o período e o número de dias da semana não forem muito extensos, não haverá tanta perda de performance. Que bom que consegui ajudar de alguma forma.

Comment: Cara deu certo... tenho agradecimentos do tamanho da galáxia! Que Deus ilumine você!